# Dados duplicados Laço de Repetição Query Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, for, while

Estou com um problema em um laço de repetição em `node js`, esta é a `query`

```
exports.getValueMsg = function() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pconn
            .pool
            .query("SELECT b.numero_serie, b.grupo_msg, b.index_msg, b.valor_msg FROM bor_msg b where b.id_tipo = '16'",
            (err, rows) => {
                if (!err) {
                    while (i<rows.rows.length) {
                        dadosMsg = rows.rows[i]; 
                        i++
                        return resolve(dadosMsg);
                    }            
                } else {
                    reject(err);
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });  
   });
}
```

ela me  retorna 5 resultados que vem deste select acima, quando faço a chamada dela neste script

```
const exec = async() => { 
    try {
      var count = Object.keys(await dbMsg.getValueMsg()).length;

        for(i; i<count; i++) {
            valueMsg = await dbMsg.getValueMsg();
            console.log(valueMsg);

            configXml = await fc.dadosXml();      
            macro = await xmlTemplates.xml_16_begin(valueMsg, configXml);      
            clientOut.write(macro);

            await fc.wait(2200);

            clientOut.write(xmlTemplates.xml_16_end(valueMsg, configXml));

            await fc.wait(3000);

            dbMsg.upStatusMsg(statusMsg, valueMsg);

            setTimeout(function() {
                if(vDataOutObj.Package.Header._attributes.Id == 116) {
                    console.log(vDataOutObj.Package.Header._attributes.Id);
                    dbMsg.upStatusMsg(statusMsg2, valueMsg);
                }
            }, 3100);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Ao invés de percorrer os resultados e trazer cada um...ele me trás resultados repetidos e não trás todos os resultados que tem na `query`...

*Obs(na minha tabela do banco não a registros repetidos) , alguém pode me indicar o que poderia ser isso e como solucionar essa minha questão ?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não ficou claro qual o problema. Analisando o código podemos melhorar algumas coisas e de repente seu problema possa ser resolvido:

- Evite utilizar variáveis globais como fez com o `i` e `dadosMsg`.
- Dentro do loop `for` você não está atribuindo um valor: `for(i = 0; i < ...`. Sendo assim seu segundo loop irá pegar o valor final da variável `i` referente a última execução do loop anterior.
- A variável `dadosMsg` é dispensável

Veja se o trecho abaixo ajuda:

```
exports.getValueMsg = function() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pconn
            .pool
            .query("SELECT b.numero_serie, b.grupo_msg, b.index_msg, b.valor_msg FROM bor_msg b where b.id_tipo = '16'",
                (err, result) => {
                    if (err) {
                        reject(err);
                    } else {
                        resolve(result);
                    }
                }
            );  
   });
}


const exec = async() => {
    const queryResult = await dbMsg.getValueMsg();
    for(let i = 0; i < queryResult.length; i++) {
        const item = queryResult[i];
        console.log(`Item ${i+1}:`, item);

        // ...
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Era basicamente isso, fiz alguns ajustes e agora está funcionando da forma certa...Muito obrigado Cara